# Chart.js Change color of the values *inside* the bars of a Bar chart

Tags: colors, label, chart.js

So what Im trying to do is to change the color of the values inside the bars of a Bar chart. I have tried all options and also have a pen where it doesnt seem to work: https://codepen.io/vbbalaji/pen/oNbwbpm

```
[![Bar Chart][1]][1]
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8lE7.png ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. You need to include the [chartjs datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app) script in order to use it.  Make sure you include this script after the main Chart.js library:  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.7.0.
2. Your `datalabels` options should be nested within the key `plugins`.

Here's the corrected config:

```js
{
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Amber", "Green"],
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: ["#db5935", "#f0ae43", "#3cba9f"],
        data: [2, -4, 6]
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    title: { display: true, text: "Health Variance" },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: "blue",
        labels: {
          title: { color: "blue", font: { weight: "bold" } },
          value: { color: "green" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Chart.js datalabels]

Here's your updated codepen: https://codepen.io/typpo/pen/oNbwxvK